# Google Speech to Text API gives a 00:00 audio length

Tags: google-api, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I have an audio clip that is about 40 minutes long. I uploaded it to GCS and use the URI for audio configuration. The audio assessment gave an estimated duration of 00:00, which is apparently wrong (see image below). The transcription result is empty as well.

[This shows the audio assessment that gave 00:00.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6kAi.png)

The file was originally in `.m4a` format. I changed it to other formats (`.wav`
and `.flac`), but they also gave a 00:00 length. The API only worked when I trimmed the audio file to the first 40 seconds and 100 seconds. It failed when I trimmed the audio file to the first 10 minutes.

Please advise if you have any idea about this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by converting the `.m4a` file with an online tool, e.g. [convertio.co](https://convertio.co/m4a-flac/) to a `FLAC` file. Then the API works  like a charm.

Originally, I directly changed the extension `m4a` to `flac` in my Windows computer. It turns out that this does not do the trick.